# H2O failed to connect in R

Tags: r, implementation, h2o

I am nt able to start the h2o in R due to version of java and receiving the below error

H2O is not running yet, starting it now...

Note:  In case of errors look at the following log files:
    C:\Users\Vaibhav\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpMBUt0r\file1db069d01678/h2o_Vaibhav_started_from_r.out
    C:\Users\Vaibhav\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpMBUt0r\file1db02fcb36fc/h2o_Vaibhav_started_from_r.err

java version "14.0.1" 2020-04-14
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 14.0.1+7)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0.1+7, mixed mode, sharing)

Starting H2O JVM and connecting: ............................................................Diagnostic HTTP Request:
   HTTP Status Code: -1
HTTP Error Message: Failed to connect to localhost port 54321: Connection refused

Error Output:
   Only Java 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 and 13 are supported, system version is 14.0.1 
Error in h2o.init(nthreads = -1, max_mem_size = "4g") : 
  H2O failed to start, stopping execution

Comment: The error is rather clear. Before loading `h2o` you'll have to install an appropriate java version, and possibly direct `h2o` to the appropriate directory. For the latter it might be simpler to uninstall the later version completely before initializing `h2o`.

Answer (score 0):

you're using Java version 14, which is not yet supported officially in H2O.

There's a JIRA to track Java 14 integration: https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-7647 .

In H2O, there's a property to override this default setting, which will let you use H2O with Java 14 at your own risk. This can be done by settings the `sys.ai.h2o.debug.allowJavaVersions` property when starting H2O.

- If started manually, use `java -Dsys.ai.h2o.debug.allowJavaVersions=14 -jar h2o.jar`
- From Python, use: `h2o.init(jvm_custom_args=["sys.ai.h2o.debug.allowJavaVersions", "14"])`
- From R, use: `h2o.init(jvm_custom_args=c("sys.ai.h2o.debug.allowJavaVersions", "14"))`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get H2O working with Java 14 by following the install instructions for the [latest stable release](http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/latest_stable.html) (currently [rel-zeno/2](http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-zeno/2/index.html)):

```
# The following two commands remove any previously installed H2O packages for R.
if ("package:h2o" %in% search()) { detach("package:h2o", unload=TRUE) }
if ("h2o" %in% rownames(installed.packages())) { remove.packages("h2o") }

# Next, we download packages that H2O depends on.
pkgs <- c("RCurl","jsonlite")
for (pkg in pkgs) {
if (! (pkg %in% rownames(installed.packages()))) { install.packages(pkg) }
}

# Now we download, install and initialize the H2O package for R.
install.packages("h2o", type="source", repos="http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-zeno/2/R")

# Finally, let's load H2O and start up an H2O cluster
library(h2o)
h2o.init()
```

You'll need to update the repos URL in the last `install.packages` line if you want a more [recent release](http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/latest_stable.html).

When I tried the answer from @pavel-pscheidl (prior to trying the above) I got the following error:

```
> h2o.init(jvm_custom_args=c("sys.ai.h2o.debug.allowJavaVersions", "14"))

H2O is not running yet, starting it now...

Note:  In case of errors look at the following log files:
    /var/folders/nx/pn7rnnx96f184jt2sdtm52_00000gp/T//RtmpTz7jEz/file88837ecffee3/h2o_username_started_from_r.out
    /var/folders/nx/pn7rnnx96f184jt2sdtm52_00000gp/T//RtmpTz7jEz/file88839672a20/h2o_username_started_from_r.err

openjdk version "14.0.2" 2020-07-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 14.0.2+12-46)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0.2+12-46, mixed mode, sharing)

Starting H2O JVM and connecting: ............................................................Diagnostic HTTP Request:
   HTTP Status Code: -1
HTTP Error Message: Failed to connect to localhost port 54321: Connection refused
 
Error Output:
   Error: Could not find or load main class sys.ai.h2o.debug.allowJavaVersions
   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sys.ai.h2o.debug.allowJavaVersions 
Error in h2o.init(jvm_custom_args = c("sys.ai.h2o.debug.allowJavaVersions",  : 
  H2O failed to start, stopping execution.
```